# Event при появлении/создании div

Tags: javascript

Есть простая функция создания элемента в теле документа:

```
Modal.prototype.show = function() {
   var self = this;
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.id = "modal" + self.id;
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
   var event = new Event('show');
   div.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

И функция удаления:

```
Modal.prototypa.hide = function(id) {
   var self = this;
   var div = document.getElementById("modal" + id);
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(div);
   var event = new Event('hide');
   div.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Когда я вешаю событие на удаление `Modal`, оно срабатывает, но не срабатывает при создании элемента. Как повесить событие на создание `<div>`, чтобы к нему можно было повесить обработчик с помощью `addEventListener`?

Comment: А где и как вы вешаете обработчики событий `show` и `hide` для `<div>`?

Comment: @Regent `document.getElementById('modal1').addEventListener('hide',function(){...})` работает, а вот `document.getElementById('modal1').addEventListener('show',function(){...})` нет. А вешаю перед закрытием `<body>`

Comment: @Regent, ну как бы модалок много может быть. А событие необходимо только для, например, первого. Может быть и `modal2`. На закрытии они все работают.

Comment: @Regent обработчики добавляются в конце файла, т.е. после всех функций с `Modal.prototype`. Файл подключен перед закрытием `</body>`.

Comment: А зачем, кстати, вам вообще события `show` и `hide`? А то я подготовил примеры, начал было писать ответ, а потом осознал, что цель этих событий мне не ясна. Что там за код такой, который нельзя просто вызвать в конце функций `.prototype.show` и `prototype.hide`?

Comment: @Regent, при показе модального окна должна выполниться определенная ф-ция. Т.к. код универсализирован для большого количества модалок, то для разных окон должна быть своя ф-ция. При `hide` событие можно навешивать на каждое окно и будут выполнятся соответствующие ф-ции. А вот для `show` почему-то не работает событие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первый подход** с использованием глобальных (в примере используется `document`, но можно использовать любого статичного родителя создаваемых `<div>`-ов. Однако лучше использовать ближайшего такого родителя) обработчиков событий:

```js
document.addEventListener("show", function(event) {
    if (event.target.id.indexOf('modal') == 0) {
        console.log(event.target.id + " is shown");
    }
});

document.addEventListener("hide", function(event) {
    if (event.target.id.indexOf('modal') == 0) {
        console.log(event.target.id + " is hidden");
    }
});

function show(id) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "modal" + id;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    var event = new Event('show', { "bubbles": true });
    div.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function hide(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById("modal" + id);
    var event = new Event('hide', { "bubbles": true });
    div.dispatchEvent(event);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(div);
}

show(1);
setTimeout(function() { show(2); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { hide(2); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function() { hide(1); }, 3000);
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

При таком подходе важно иметь возможность отфильтровать в обработчиках событий только события для нужных элементов. Также необходимо указывать `{ "bubbles": true }` при создании события для того, чтобы событие "всплыло" до родителя. По той же причине удалять элемент со страницы можно только после вызова события.

**Второй подход** с использованием глобального обработчика `show` и обработчика события `hide` только для конкретного элемента, добавляемого при создании элемента:

```js
document.addEventListener("show", function(event) {
    if (event.target.id.indexOf('modal') == 0) {
        console.log(event.target.id + " is shown");
    }
});

function show(id) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "modal" + id;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    var event = new Event('show', { "bubbles": true });
    div.dispatchEvent(event);
    div.addEventListener("hide", function() {
        console.log(div.id + " is hidden");
    });
}

function hide(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById("modal" + id);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(div);
    var event = new Event('hide');
    div.dispatchEvent(event);
}

show(1);
setTimeout(function() { show(2); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { hide(2); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function() { hide(1); }, 3000);
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

**Третий подход** с использованием просто функций (если обработчик добавления, равно как и удаления, элементов всегда один) вместо событий:

```js
function onShown(element) {
    if (element.id.indexOf('modal') == 0) {
        console.log(element.id + " is shown");
    }
};

function onHidden(element) {
    if (element.id.indexOf('modal') == 0) {
        console.log(element.id + " is hidden");
    }
};

function show(id) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "modal" + id;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    onShown(div);
}

function hide(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById("modal" + id);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(div);
    onHidden(div);
}

show(1);
setTimeout(function() { show(2); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { hide(2); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function() { hide(1); }, 3000);
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: т.е. нельзя вешать `addEventListener` на сам элемент при создании? А то как-то криво получается: для скрытия можно просто навесить слушателя и использовать необходимые функции, а для показа так извращаться. Других вариантов, видимо, нет?

Comment: @МаксимВласов можно, но вот это как раз и будет извращением: зачем добавлять обработчик события для `div`, который будет **сразу же** вызван, буквально в следующей строке кода? Кстати, _delegated event handlers_ - это не извращение, а часто используемая вещь для динамически созданных элементов.

Comment: Просто хотелось сделать событийную модель, похожую на Bootstrap. Там как раз есть событие `show.bs.modal`, но оно навешивается на `focus` элемента.

Comment: @МаксимВласов событийная модель - дело неплохое, но всё должно быть в рамках разумного. Добавлять обработчик события для одного элемента, которое генерируется сразу же - это не здорово. При таком подходе каждую строку кода можно затолкать в обработчик какого-то события, после чего генерировать это событие, но это будет очень странно выглядеть. Если у вас событие `show` может генерироваться для элемента где-то ещё - это другое дело. Но, насколько я понял, у вас для элемента один раз происходит событие `show` и один раз - событие `hide`.

Comment: @МаксимВласов как бы то ни было, во втором подходе я продемонстрировал добавление обработчика события `hide` для элемента сразу после его создания. По аналогии вы можете добавить обработчик события `show`.